# Android:Sqlite database errors

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing code for a database to fetch data in an activity which contains three fields,
namely `Truck_id`, `employee_id`, and `password`.

I am getting some errors; below is my code:
Please help me as I am new to android:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// default system path of your application database.
// private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.tanzanite.operasoft/databases/";

private static String DB_PATH = "/sdcard/";

private static String DB_NAME = "snowman";

private static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private Context myContext;

private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;


/**
 * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
 * access to the application assets and resources.
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    this.myContext = context;
}

public void TestAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.myContext= context;
}

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Login";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 2;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME="snowman";


public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "employee_id";  
public static final String COLUMN_TRUCKID = "truck_id";


public static final int NAME_COLUMN=1;
public static final String KEY_CREATION_DATE="creation_date";
public static final String KEY_TASK="task";


/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_NAME + "( " + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                            + COLUMN_TRUCKID+ " text not null, "
                            + COLUMN_NAME+ " text not null, )";


public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        //this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

public DataBaseHelper open() throws SQLException
{   
        //myDataBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
}


/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath ); 
         SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);

        //throw new Error("Database does't exist yet.");

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    return;

}

public String logindetails()
{
    open();
    Cursor c=myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME,
             new String[]{COLUMN_NAME,
                          COLUMN_TRUCKID,

                          },null, null, null, null, null);
    String b="";

    c.close();
    myDataBase.close();
    return b;
}   

public void insert(String a, String b){

    ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
    vals.put(COLUMN_TRUCKID, "CM-3456");
    vals.put(COLUMN_NAME,"Sachin");
    //vals.put(KEY_PIN, "12345");

    vals.put(COLUMN_TRUCKID, "HR-6788");
    vals.put(COLUMN_NAME,"Sameer");
    //vals.put(KEY_PIN, "54321");

    vals.put(COLUMN_ID, "AM-6123");
    vals.put(COLUMN_NAME,"Sahu");
    //vals.put(KEY_PIN, "3452");


    myDataBase.close();


}

public Cursor fetchdata()
{
    open();
    Cursor c=myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME,
         new String[]{COLUMN_NAME,
            COLUMN_TRUCKID,

                      },null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToLast();
    myDataBase.close();
    return c;
}


public static SQLiteDatabase getDataBase() {
    return myDataBase;

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{

    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.v( "Press_Data","exception in table created");
    }
```

}

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

The errors are..

```
06-14 18:22:27.233: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_CONCURRENT freed 757K, 48% free 3547K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 4ms+4ms
06-14 18:22:27.393: I/net.osmand(25087): BaseOsmandRender Init render default for 738 ms
06-14 18:22:27.523: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 123K, 46% free 3635K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 62ms
06-14 18:22:27.633: D/AndroidRuntime(25087): Shutting down VM
06-14 18:22:27.633: W/dalvikvm(25087): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tanzanite.operasoft/com.tanzanite.operasoft.activity.Sw_LoginScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at com.tanzanite.operasoft.database.DataBaseHelper.fetchdata(DataBaseHelper.java:222)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at com.tanzanite.operasoft.activity.Sw_LoginScreenActivity.onCreate(Sw_LoginScreenActivity.java:52)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-14 18:22:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    ... 11 more
06-14 18:28:37.603: D/dalvikvm(26440): GC_CONCURRENT freed 757K, 48% free 3541K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 3ms+3ms
06-14 18:28:37.773: I/net.osmand(26440): BaseOsmandRender Init render default for 611 ms
06-14 18:28:37.873: D/dalvikvm(26440): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 122K, 46% free 3633K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 51ms
06-14 18:28:38.013: D/AndroidRuntime(26440): Shutting down VM
06-14 18:28:38.013: W/dalvikvm(26440): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tanzanite.operasoft/com.tanzanite.operasoft.activity.Sw_LoginScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at com.tanzanite.operasoft.database.DataBaseHelper.fetchdata(DataBaseHelper.java:222)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at com.tanzanite.operasoft.activity.Sw_LoginScreenActivity.onCreate(Sw_LoginScreenActivity.java:52)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-14 18:28:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(26440):    ... 11 more
06-14 18:40:55.423: D/dalvikvm(29844): GC_CONCURRENT freed 759K, 48% free 3553K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+3ms
06-14 18:40:55.633: I/net.osmand(29844): BaseOsmandRender Init render default for 841 ms
06-14 18:40:55.773: D/dalvikvm(29844): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 122K, 46% free 3633K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 58ms
06-14 18:40:55.913: D/AndroidRuntime(29844): Shutting down VM
06-14 18:40:55.913: W/dalvikvm(29844): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tanzanite.operasoft/com.tanzanite.operasoft.activity.Sw_LoginScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at com.tanzanite.operasoft.database.DataBaseHelper.fetchdata(DataBaseHelper.java:223)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at com.tanzanite.operasoft.activity.Sw_LoginScreenActivity.onCreate(Sw_LoginScreenActivity.java:52)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-14 18:40:55.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29844):    ... 11 more
06-14 19:12:06.293: D/dalvikvm(5930): GC_CONCURRENT freed 763K, 48% free 3549K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 4ms+5ms
06-14 19:12:06.443: I/net.osmand(5930): BaseOsmandRender Init render default for 689 ms
06-14 19:12:06.553: D/dalvikvm(5930): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 120K, 47% free 3632K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 64ms
06-14 19:12:06.703: D/AndroidRuntime(5930): Shutting down VM
06-14 19:12:06.703: W/dalvikvm(5930): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tanzanite.operasoft/com.tanzanite.operasoft.activity.Sw_LoginScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at com.tanzanite.operasoft.database.DataBaseHelper.fetchdata(DataBaseHelper.java:224)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at com.tanzanite.operasoft.activity.Sw_LoginScreenActivity.onCreate(Sw_LoginScreenActivity.java:49)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: @GrahamBorland Can't you see them? I had to scroll the page :D

Comment: @user1423111 I could tell you why do you get one of the errors but instead I will recommend that you learn a bit about working with databases in android.

Comment: @user1423111 I would suggest you significantly edit your post to show only the lines where you're getting the errors, and state what you've tried when debugging to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you log i see

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930): at com.tanzanite.operasoft.database.DataBaseHelper.fetchdata(DataBaseHelper.java:224) 
06-14 19:12:06.723: E/AndroidRuntime(5930): at com.tanzanite.operasoft.activity.Sw_LoginScreenActivity.onCreate(Sw_LoginScreenActivity.java:49)
```

So, you need use debuger and set breackpoints on

Sw_LoginScreenActivity.java - on line 49 (i think there you try to fetch data)

DataBaseHelper.java - on 224 - there you try to fetch data from myDataBase

```
public Cursor fetchdata()
{
    open();
    Cursor c=myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME,
         new String[]{COLUMN_NAME,
            COLUMN_TRUCKID,

                      },null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToLast();
    myDataBase.close();
    return c;
}
```

But, in open() method

```
public DataBaseHelper open() throws SQLException
{   
        //myDataBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
}
```

You comment line with creating database instance - so next line "Cursor c=myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME," it's not correct, because myDataBase is null.

You did not open connection to database.

Answer (score 1):

You problem lies in here (a Null Pointer Exception) according to the logcat:

```
public String logindetails() 
{ 
    open(); 
    Cursor c=myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TRUCKID, },
        null, null, null, null, null); 
    String b=""; 
    c.close(); 
    myDataBase.close(); 
    return b; 
}
```

I see several issues...

First and foremost, you should not be trying to open/close your database in methods of your db helper.  The db should be opened and closed by another class that instantiates the dbhelper and uses the instantiated class methods to open and close the db.

Second, you have an extra comma in your table column array list.

Third you seem to be calling a cursor for no reason... you get it and don't do anything with it, then close it.

Fourth, you set an empty string, do nothing with it and then return it.

It should look more like this I think:

In your calling class:

```
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);  // instantiate the helper
mDbHelper.openDataBase();    // open the db
String ldetails = mDbHelper.logindetails();  // get logindetails string from db
```

In you DatabaseHelper class:

```
public String logindetails() 
{ 
    String b=""; 
    Cursor c=myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TRUCKID, },
        null, null, null, null, null); 
    c.moveToFirst();
    // Insert code to get data from cursor to string
    c.close(); 
    return b; 
}
```

Comment: mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);  // instantiate the helper
      mDbHelper.openDataBase();    // open the db
      String ldetails = mDbHelper.logindetails(); // get logindetails string from db
      
       String[] truck_id = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adptTruck=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,truck_id);
      
    String[] employee_id = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adptEMP=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,employee_id);